# How can I add JADE to Eclipse and make a program using JADE?

Tags: java, agents-jade

I want programming in jade for first time.How i can add JADE in eclipse and use it? I want to add JADE to eclipse, but I cannot add it to libraries in Eclipse.

Comment: Searching "JADE for Eclipse" in Google turned [this](http://wrjih.wordpress.com/2008/11/29/running-jade-under-eclipse/) link up.

Comment: It would certainly help us help you if you provided a link to the *JADE* project you are trying to use, to avoid any ambiguity. "JADE" is not exactly a rare name in the software world, you know...

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean Eclipse, so there are several Jade plugin out there, for example :

- [JadClipse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jadclipse/)
- [EJADE](http://selab.fbk.eu/dnguyen/ejade/index.html)
- [jade-fw](http://code.google.com/p/jade-fw/)

Comment: thank's. But i want to know " how  can i add Jade in Eclipse libraries?

Comment: See the link posted by Jeffrey